# build release Ionic does not generate

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to build the APK to post my plea on Ionic in the Play Store.
But when it comes to the command below I get the error:

> PS C:\Projetos\XXX> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA
> -digestalg SHA1 -keystore android.keystore platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk
>
> android-app-key Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M Enter Passphrase for
> keystore: jarsigner:
> unable to open jar file:
> platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk

And the release is not generated in the APK folder. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem may occur because of the following reasons  :

1. app-release-unsigned.apk does not exist
2. when executing above command you are not in the release folder, release folder can be found in platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release
3. keystore does not exist

Verify that you are following these steps

- after running **ionic cordova build --release android** make sure the build is successful and release folder is created under, the path is  **platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release**.
- once release folder is created navigate to that folder through terminal
- once you reach there generate key store by running following command `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
  you can change the key name to anything, in this example the key name is **my-release-key**, alias name is also up to you, here alias name is **alias_name**.
- the key will be created under the release folder, save this key somewhere else to publish subsequent builds, also save alias name.
- Once key is created run `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk alias_name` here put the same alias name in place of **alias_name** and keystore name in place of **my-release-key.keystore** what you choose in step 4, make sure you release apk name is same as **app-release-unsigned.apk** if it is different change it as well.
- in the end run `zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk myapp.apk`, to compress you app, this will create the compressed apk with name **myapp.apk** it is the same apk that you will use to publish.

Comment: can you tell me the location of the apk

Answer (score 1):

Checked whether android.keystore is located in C:\Projetos\XXX directory. Also check app-release-unsigned.apk is present on platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk this path.

Answer (score 1):

I was typing the wrong command. The correct one to generate is

> ionic cordova build --release

and then, to generate the key for the first time, I used these commands:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore xxx.keystore -alias xxx-app-key -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore GestaoDespesas.keystore platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk xxx-app-key

.\zipalign -v 4 platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\xxx.apk xxx.apk
```